# How does BB-8 not know that R2-D2 is in low power mode?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *[The Force Awakens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* when the characters get to the Resistance base, we see BB-8 remove the tarp over R2-D2, and seemingly try to wake him up.  At this point, C-3P0 points out that R2 is in low power mode.

But, if BB-8 is the astromech for the Resistance's most daring pilot (both of whom MUST have been at the base many times), how does BB-8 not already know this?

Comment: I've always watched that scene as C-3PO restating the fact to deter or remind BB-8.

Comment: I interpreted it as C-3PO being equal parts condescending towards BB-8 (aka "Hey stupid, you should be able to tell he's in low power mode"), and protective of his friend ("R2 clearly wants to be left alone, stop bothering him.")

Comment: Is there any reason to assume anyone actually cared enough about R2D2 to tell BB8 about him? He's been essentially a hunk of lifeless metal for years. He was even covered with a sheet. I'd imagine most of the Resistance fighters didn't even know R2 was on the base, and the ones who did probably didn't think it was important enough to talk about.

Comment: Why would BB-8 know that? R2-D2 wouldn't be broadcasting that he's in low power mode, *because he's in low power mode.*

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh R2 is a main character in all 6 movies.  BB-8, having spent a ton of time at the base, should know that one of the highest profile members of the resistance is out of commission.  And he seems to know where R2 is, since he went straight there to remove the tarp.

Comment: @JohnSensebe No, but R2 being as high profile as he is, seems to me like it would be a big deal.

Comment: @DaveJohnson In that case, maybe R2 had recently been moved out of storage. BB-8 just rushed over because he recognized the feet. I guess this is all speculation, but you're also making a lot of assumptions about the importance of R2 and BB-8, remember that a lot of people in *Star Wars* don't care about drods.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Exactly, maybes and speculation.  And assumptions.  Hence the question :)

Comment: @DaveJohnson - High profile? Did R2 get a medal at the end of *Episode IV*? **No!** He's a piece of equipment. That is, until the revolution. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) (sorta) covers this. Apparently BB-8 is *aware* of R2-D2 and the fact that he likely possesses the remainder of the map, but he hasn't come across him before.

After a considerable amount of searching, he finds the storage closet where they'd shoved him.

> THE SEARCH HAD taken BB-8 some time, but he finally found what he was looking for. Or rather, who. Or maybe both, since an intelligent droid technically qualified as both a who and a what. In the dark, dusty storeroom he rolled over to the R2 unit and beeped a greeting, the transmission sequence too rapid and too exhaustive for any human to follow. It didn’t matter. There was no response from the immobile R2 unit.
>   BB-8 tried again, utilizing a different droid language. When that also failed, he moved forward and gave the other mechanical a forceful nudge. Like everything else, that too failed to generate a response.
>   Observing the unsuccessful interaction, C-3PO came forward out of the shadows.
>   “You’re wasting your time, I’m afraid. It is very doubtful that Artoo would have the rest of the map in his backup data.” When BB-8 queried the protocol droid, C-3PO responded without hesitation.
>   “He’s been locked down in self-imposed low-power mode. He just hasn’t been the same since Master Luke went away.”

Note that this "low-power mode" is something that's pretty unique to R2-D2 and is a mixture of information overload and a self-imposed sulk.